# How to send password reset email from django using django-rest-framework and React

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a website in the backend i'm using (django,django-rest-framework) and frontend (React.js). I'm not clearly understand how do i create restfull api for password reset email.

Answer (score 0):

The library Django Rest Auth (different from django rest framework's `auth` app) helps with this. https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth

**Backend**

Install `rest_auth` into `INSTALLED_APPS` on the backend, and set up a URL

```
urlpatterns = [
  ...
  path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
]
```

**Frontend**
Once that's in place, you can send a post request to the password reset endpoint, and it'll send out an email using Django's built-in mail handling (I use `django-anymail` to get it to send through mailgun, but any email backend will work)

This is a snippet from react-native, but you can use an equivalent web library like axios or jQuery to make the post request.

```
  async resetPassword() {
    const { email } = this.state;
    fetch("https://mywebsite.com/api/v1/rest-auth/password/reset/", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({email}),
    })
  }
```